# Error while using sqoop to copy data to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, sqoop

I am using sqoop to copy a Postgres table to s3 using the following command

```
sqoop import -m 1 --connect jdbc:postgresql://xx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/prod_db --username user_ro --password user_pwd --table content --target-dir s3://test/user/sqoop_test --as-avrodatafile
```

This works for the first time. Before the next execution I deleted the target directory using:

```
aws s3 rm s3://test/user/sqoop_test
```

Next execution of sqoop results in following error:

```
18/07/21 05:31:53 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.consistency.exception.ConsistencyException: Directory 'user/sqoop_test' present in the metadata but not s3
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.consistency.ConsistencyCheckerS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(ConsistencyCheckerS3FileSystem.java:453)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.consistency.ConsistencyCheckerS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(ConsistencyCheckerS3FileSystem.java:380)
```

I have also tried doing "emrfs delete..." followed by "emrfs import..." & "emrfs sync.." But that didn't help resolve the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The metadata is specifying "auser/sqoop_test". This does not match "test/user/sqoop_test". I think that you have a path problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley sorry I was masking out userId, password, host name , path etc before posting the question in the command as well in the log output. The directory references user/sqoop_test and not auser/sqoop_test as I posted originally. I have updated it. What I am not able to figure out is - where does it keeps it metadata and how to clean that out. I thought emrfs commands will do that but it didn't.